# A faster way to change the foreground colour of RichText?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, rtf

I have a Windows Store App which features a `RichEditBox`. This box can be themed with background and font colours. The text can be saved to an RTF document. In order to do that, I need to format the text to a black font (for instance, if the foreground colour is set to white or yellow, it'll be almost illegible if opened in Wordpad)

I have the following code to do this:

```
string content = string.Empty;
editor.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out content);
autosave_helper.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, content);
autosave_helper.Document.Selection.StartPosition = 0;
autosave_helper.Document.Selection.EndPosition = content.Length;
ITextSelection selectedText = autosave_helper.Document.Selection;
if (selectedText != null)
{
    selectedText.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Black;
}
autosave_helper.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out content);
```

The code works, but on a document of 20,000 words, it takes about 20 seconds to do so. I've timed each line of code, and was surprised to find `selectedText.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Black;` was the slowest part. everything else executes in a split second, but this formatting line takes around 20 seconds each time.

I've come up with a workaround / ugly hack which directly changes the colour header in the RTF source, but this doesn't work all the time.

How to I change the colour of my RichText content without using the above, incredibly slow code?

**Note:** before anyone suggests it, having an invisible RichEditBox with foreground colour set to black **does not work** as the colour header in the RichText document overrides the Foreground colour of the control (as it should).

Comment: RichTextBox.Foreground and RichTextBlock.Foreground look attractive.  The documentation is totally inadequate to take that further.

Comment: Hans, the control in Question is the **RichEditBox** control, not RichTextBox, which is not available in Windows Store Apps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Unfortunately setting RichEditBox.Foreground has no effect on the text within, only text newly created in that control. If I load an existing RTF into it, the color remains the same.